# when using ImGui with Glut it does not show any objects

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, imgui

I'm coding a rendering engine in C++ with OpenGL and GLUT and trying to integrate ImGUI into my engine, but I have a problem. it either renders the gui and only the background (no objects), or it only renders the objects and background (no GUI). This code:

```cpp
glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
glutIdleFunc(renderScene);
glutReshapeFunc(sizeChange);
glutSpecialUpFunc(releaseKey);
glutSpecialFunc(pressKey);
IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
ImGui::CreateContext();
ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO(); (void)io;
ImGui::StyleColorsLight();
ImGui_ImplGLUT_Init();
ImGui_ImplGLUT_InstallFuncs();
ImGui_ImplOpenGL2_Init();
```

creates this:
[image]

and this code:

```cpp
IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
ImGui::CreateContext();
ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO(); (void)io;
ImGui::StyleColorsLight();
ImGui_ImplGLUT_Init();
ImGui_ImplGLUT_InstallFuncs();
ImGui_ImplOpenGL2_Init();

glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
glutIdleFunc(renderScene);
glutReshapeFunc(sizeChange);
glutSpecialUpFunc(releaseKey);
glutSpecialFunc(pressKey);
```

creates this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that GLUT callback handlers in both of your examples are set both manually (`glut...Func`) and by ImGui via `ImGui_ImplGLUT_InstallFuncs`. The latter sets default ImGui handlers for many GLUT callbacks (see the [source](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/268565079c56600c197602683391a1bc8afba014/backends/imgui_impl_glut.cpp#L173)), in particular `glutReshapeFunc` is used to set current window resize callback to `ImGui_ImplGLUT_ReshapeFunc` ([source](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/268565079c56600c197602683391a1bc8afba014/backends/imgui_impl_glut.cpp#L287)), which sets internal ImGui display size according to given parameters.

When in the second example `glutReshapeFunc(sizeChange)` gets called, ImGui handler gets unset, so it doesn't get called during window resize (which, in particular, happens also before the first display according to the GLUT [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node48.html#SECTION00083000000000000000)), which leaves internal ImGui state not set properly. In the first example, the situation is reversed - your reshape handler `sizeChange` gets unset and replaced by ImGui one, so initialization and rendering of your cube doesn't go as intended because `sizeChange` never gets called.

To resolve this, you can omit `ImGui_ImplGLUT_InstallFuncs` and use your GLUT handlers while, apart from custom logic, calling default ImGui handlers from them if they are present and their functionality is needed (you can see what default handlers exist by inspecting the sources linked above). E.g. you can change `sizeChange` like this:

```
void sizeChange(int w, int h)
{
    // Your logic
    // ...
    ImGui_ImplGLUT_ReshapeFunc(w, h);
}
```

If you want key presses and releases to be registered by ImGui as well as your own code, you may change `releaseKey` and `pressKey` in a similar way by adding, respectively, `ImGui_ImplGLUT_SpecialUpFunc` and `ImGui_ImplGLUT_SpecialFunc` calls to them.